# Java Generic instanceof not using inheritance

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

**What I'm trying to do:**

Type checking with Java inheritance dynamically. I have two classes: 1) `com.example.Event` and 2) `com.example.TransactionEvent` which extends `com.example.Event`. I have a function `Class<?> type` which returns the type to check against.

**Code:**

```
public class Event{}

public class TransactionEvent extends Event{}

public interface Listener
{
    public Class<?> type();
}

public void checkType(Event obj, Listener listener)
{
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(listener.type().toString());

    if (obj.getClass().isInstance(listener.type()))
         System.out.println("yay!");
}
```

**Output:**

```
class com.example.TransactionEvent
class com.example.Event

(no Yay)
```

Isn't `TransactionEvent` an instanceof `Event` since it inherits from it?

Comment: It inherits under the different erasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
if (listener.type ().isInstance (obj))
```

or, which is virtually the same:

```
if (listener.type ().isAssignableFrom (obj.getClass ()))
```